# Iterator in ArcGIS with for loop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, iterator

[image][image]I have a problem represented in that when I make an iteration with For loop, it does not return many results as it is specified, and instead it just return one value. I am using a simple model builder with for iterator and buffer of 100 to 400 with 100 increment.

[image: Model]

What do I do to get the specific results?

Comment: thanks for your response, I appreciate, I am using a simple model builder with for iterator and buffer of 100 to 400 with 100 increment.but as I said it returns one result.

Comment: You are probably overwriting the output each iteration. How are you naming the output of Buffer? A screenshot would help

Comment: can you send me your e-mail to send you the exported image? I have technical problem to send the screen shot

Comment: If you are using windows operating system just press print screen to copy the screen, crop it in MS paint then upload it to your question.

Comment: I had upload it, you can see

Comment: Show what you have in the For loop. Your output is a file geodatabase?

Comment: C:\Users\Abdalla\Documents\ArcGIS\Default.gdb\ROADS_Buffer24%Value%   this is the out put path

Comment: what is inside For loop is the first buffer and the last and the increment of 100 meter every time

Comment: Can you add one more screen shot to your question, how you set the buffer tool up? From this screen shot it looks OK but we need to see how you are setting up the parameters of the buffer tool.

Comment: I had uploaded two buffer screenshot

Comment: I am still waiting,,,

Answer (score 1):

I think you didn't define values in the (For iteration).

please check my ModelBuilder and it works perfectly:

As you did in your ModelBuilder

[image]

Define the values of the buffer (e.g from 10 to 50 each 10m)

In your case (100 , 400 , 100)

[image]

Define your parameters and output name (e.g AOI_%Value%.shp)

[image]

Run! Successfully

[image]

Outputs! everything good

[image]